# A question related to the index of a Jordan curve

Tags: calculus, curves

**Problem.** *Let $f,g : [0,1]\to\mathbb R$ continuous, such that
$$
f(0)=f(1)\qquad\text{and}\qquad g(1)-g(0)=2.
$$
Show that there exist $x,y\in [0,1]$, such that $x<y$ while
$$
f(x)=f(y)\qquad\text{and}\qquad g(y)-g(x)=1.
$$*

A proof of this can be derived from the fact that the index, with respect to a Jordan curve, of a point not belonging to the curve can only be $-1,0$ or $1$.

I was wondering whether this problem can be shown in and elementary fashion, and without the use of Algebraic Topology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here’s a proof where analysis is used in place of algebraic topology (although it’s clear that it’s really algebraic topology in disguise).

By approximation, it is enough to show the result when $f,g$ are $C^2$. Define the paths $\alpha(t)=(f(t)-f(0),g(t)-g(0)-1)$ and $\beta(t)=(f(1)-f(1-t),g(1)-g(1-t)-1)$. Both paths are $C^2$, with values in $\mathbb{C}$, from $-i$ to $i$. Moreover, $\alpha(t)+\beta(1-t)=0$.

Let $\psi(x,y)=(f(y)-f(x))+i(g(y)-g(x)-1)$ for $0 \leq x,y \leq 1$, and $\gamma_s(t)=\psi(s(1-t),(1-s)t+s)$ for $0 \leq s,t \leq 1$. One can check that $\gamma_s$ is $C^2$, $\gamma_s(0)=\psi(s,s)=-i$, $\gamma_s(1)=\psi(0,1)=i$, $\gamma_0(t)=\psi(0,t)=\alpha(t)$, $\gamma_1(t)=\beta(t)$.

If some $\gamma_s(t)$ is zero, we are done.

Assume this doesn’t happen. Let $I(s)=\int_0^1{\frac{\gamma_s’(t)}{\gamma_s(t)}\,dt}$. Write $\alpha(t)=r_1(t)e^{i\phi(t)}$, then $\phi(0)=-\pi/2$, $\phi(1)=\pi/2+2ik\pi$, and then $I(0)=(2k+1)i\pi$. But since $\beta(t)=-\alpha(1-t)$, $I(1)=-I(0)$ so $I(1) \neq I(0)$.

Now we’ll show that $I$ is constant. Because $\gamma$ was chosen regular enough, $I$ is $C^1$ and $I’(s)=\int_0^1{\left(\frac{(\partial_{st}\gamma_s)(t)}{\gamma(t)}-\frac{\gamma_s’(t)(\partial_s\gamma_s)(t)}{\gamma_s^2(t)}\right)\,dt}$. But what is in the integral is actually $\partial_t\left(\frac{(\partial_s\gamma_s)(t)}{\gamma_s(t)}\right)$, and thus $I’(s)=\frac{(\partial_s\gamma_s)(1)}{\gamma_s(1)}-\frac{(\partial_s\gamma_s)(0)}{\gamma_s(0)}=0$ since $\gamma_s(1)=i,\gamma_s(0)=-i$. So $I’=0$ and thus $I$ is constant. Contradiction.

Comment: "By approximation, it is enough to show the result when $f,g$ are $C^2$" : could you expand on this a little ?

Comment: $\psi$ can be defined whatever $f,g$ are, and we want to show that $0 \in \psi([0,1])^2$. Assume this isn’t the case for some pair $(f,g)$: then there is $\epsilon >0$ such that $\psi([0,1]^2)$ doesn’t meet $2\epsilon([-1,1]+[-1,1]i)$. Then, for any pair $(f_1,g_1)$ with $\|f-f_1\|_{\infty} <\epsilon,\|g-g_1\|_{\infty}<\epsilon$, $\psi_{f_1,g_1}([0,1]^2)$ will not contain zero either. But we can find $f_1,g_1$ close enough to $f,g$ satisfying the requirements of the answer. A contradiction.

Comment: @Mindlack Great answer. Let me suggest some minor simplifications. It is not hard to show that: *If $\gamma : [0,1]\to\mathbb C$* is piecewise $C^1$, $\gamma(t)\ne 0$, for all $t\in[0,1]$, and $\gamma(1)=-\gamma(0)$, then $\int_0^1\frac{\gamma'(t)}{\gamma(t)}dt=(2k+1)\pi i$, for some $k\in\mathbb Z$. (Just add a half-circle to $\gamma$ and obtain a closed curve.) Next, as $I(s)$ is continuous with respect to $s$, and $\frac{1}{\pi i}I(s)\in\mathbb Z$, then $I(s)$ is constant.

Comment: @Mindlack Can you modify the proof if the original assumption $g(1)-g(0)=2$ is replaced by $g(1)-g(0)=n$, where $n\ge 2$ is a positive integer?

Comment: Why the downvote(s)? For the other comments, I like the modifications that you suggested. And if $g(1)-g(0)=n\geq 2$, just replace $g$ with $2g/n$, no?